# Bootstrap 5 JavaScript not working, what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, webstorm

Pardon me if I am missing something obvious. I am using WebStorm to write a website and wanted to experiment with Bootstrap. Now the problem is that I'm pretty sure the Bootstrap's JavaScript isn't working. For example, I can't toggle a div with a "collapse" class, the Navbar "active" class isn't working as well. Here is my code. UPDATE: updated code, I should also add my javascript is working, but the bootstrap javascript isn't

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Shachar's Website</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- My StyleSheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-info " href="#">Logo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler bg-info menu-icon-container" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-info" onclick="animateMenu(this)">
            <div class="menu-icon1"></div>
            <div class="menu-icon2"></div>
            <div class="menu-icon3"></div>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-info">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <a href="#bonus" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse">Test1</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="bonus">
        Test2
    </div>
    <div id="homepage-body" class=""></div>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+ mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- My JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: your mistake is to have placed your script in the head part of the HTML (and without any directives).

Comment: I moved it to the bottom, and put my script after it. Didn't seem to solve anything. I don't know what I am missing because now the body closes right after the two script tags and its not solving anything

Comment: I should add my javascript is working, only the bootsrap javascript isn't

Comment: update your question with your current correction. and I could maybe understand what it is to answer you

Comment: Just did, sorry still new to stack overflow

Comment: your page is missing the doctype, as well as the incoming and outgoing HTML tags, it's not a good idea, and this can be an explanation

Comment: I actually have all of that, but when I add it to stack overflow as code, it messes up the display so I omitted it. I have it in my code

Comment: writing that "it does not work" is not acceptable, there is necessarily an error message in the console of your browser.

Comment: I didn't think to check it, so thank you for the tip. There actually is something weird in the browser. I see these two error messages upon loading the page.

Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' with computed SHA-384 integrity 'OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3'. The resource has been blocked.

Comment: Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+ mo//f6V8Qbsw3'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.

Comment: you have a permission issue with your setup, it's not an HTML/JS coding issue. your computer is probably infected with a virus.

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` needs to be placed before `</body>` and add integrity and crossorigin. In general, like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+ mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Here is the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: I added the integrity and crossorigin, still doesn't work. I should also add my javascript worked both when it was in the header and now as well when I moved it next to the bootstrap script line. Only the bootstrap javascript is failing to work.

Comment: Try adding bootstrap to the very end after your script and see if bootstrap works after that.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately, it's the same situation